# Changing text of HTML element using Javascript class and addEventListener

Tags: javascript, html

I want to change the text of an HTML div using a Javascript class object by attaching `addEventListener` function to an HTML button. When the button is clicked, instead of displaying "Red" in the div, the "undefined" text is shown. However, if I directly call the function `changeColor` using a class object, the right value is shown. I apologize for such a naïve query being newer to the field. I am following tutorials on w3schools. My code is below:

```js
class Header {
  constructor() {
    this.mystring = "Red";
  }

  changeColor() {
    document.getElementById("div1").innerHTML = this.mystring;
  }
}

//create object of class
const myheader = new Header();

// This code does not work and shows undefined in the div   
document.getElementById("btn").addEventListener('click', myheader.changeColor);

// This code works and shows Red in the div
// myheader.changeColor();
```

```html
<button id="btn">Click Me!</button>

<div id="div1"></div>
```

Comment: You should use `.textContent`, and not `.innerHTML` otherwise you'll introduce an XSS vulnerability to your page.

Comment: Change `document.getElementById("btn").addEventListener('click', myheader.changeColor);` to `document.getElementById("btn").addEventListener('click', myheader.changeColor.bind(myheader) );` and it will work.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You sent `myheader.changeColor` function as a parameter without its context.
Just use [bind](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Function/bind) method.

```js
class Header {
  constructor() {
    this.mystring = "Red";
  }

  changeColor() {
    document.getElementById("div1").innerHTML = this.mystring;
  }
}

//create object of class
const myheader = new Header();

// This code does not work and shows undefined in the div   
document.getElementById("btn").addEventListener('click', myheader.changeColor.bind(myheader));

// This code works and shows Red in the div
// myheader.changeColor();
```

```html
<button id="btn">Click Me!</button>

<div id="div1"></div>
```

Comment: Thank you, I want to add a bit more explanation for newbies like me. When I write this code: 

document.getElementById('btn').addEventListener('click', myheader.changeColor);

Then, in the changeColor() method, the "this" object will be representing the "button" object to which the event listener is attached. And this is how the "this" object will behave in the method:

changeColor() 
  {
   this.style.backgroundColor="red";  // will change background color of button
   this.textContent = "hello"; // will change text of button 
  }

To change value of "mystring" we need "bind" call

Comment: Also, if we want to avoid use of "bind", then we can use "arrow functions". With an arrow function, "this" represents the Header object no matter who called the function